# Access web project on IIS from Virtual machine

Tags: asp.net, iis, virtual-machine, web-deployment, web-development-server

I have a web project in my local machine running Windows 7. 
I run this project and it becomes (localhost : 53567 / Relatorio). 
Then i have a windows XP virtual machine and i want it to access this URL. 
Through the virtual machine cmd i can ping my local machine from its IP (192.168.1.237), but when i put (192.168.1.237: 53567 / Relatorio) on the browser, i cant access it. I've already tried adding an inbound rule for this 53567 port, but still no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great blog post on how to set that up:  http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer